# C: Best way to index the digits in an integer

Tags: c, indexing, binary

If I have an

```
int i = 11110001
```

How would I be able to convert this int into an int array where

```
int array[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is _i_ supposed to be base 2 or base 10?

Comment: its supposed to be base 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little different approach and `snprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i = 11110001;
    char arr[9]; //8 digits + \0
    int array[8];
    if ((snprintf(arr,9,"%d", i) == 8) { //return the 8 characters that were printed
       int c;
       for(c = 0; c < 8; c++)
           array[c] = arr[c] - '0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: I'm assuming positive values only

Comment: From a comment by the OP: "its supposed to be base 2"

Comment: So OP accepted this answer, even though he said that "1111001" is supposed to be *base 2*? Amazing.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind confused me too after you mention it

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
#include <math.h>

char * convertNumber(unsigned int i) {
    /* unsigned int length = (int)(log10((float)i)) + 1; */
    /* char * arr = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char)), * x = arr; */
    char * arr = malloc(8);
    char * x = arr;
    do 
    {
        *x++ = i% 10;
        i/= 10;
    } while (i != 0);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Is there no simpler way without including math?

Comment: @Sean:- Any specific reason why you dont want math?

Comment: You could avoid using log10 (from math lib) if you just choose a fixed array size which is "big enough" (23 elements would handle upto a 64 bit int)  -- Alternatively, you could use malloc/realloc to get/grow what you need.

Comment: @JohnHascall: Feel free to edit the answer if you think it lacks some better approach. I appreciate edits :)

Comment: Also forgot to mention the number i will always be 8 digits in length.

Comment: Then changing that line in the answer to `unsigned int length = 8;` should solve your issue with using the math lib.

Comment: The OP also "forgot to mention" that, in `int i = 11110001`, that is a binary representation, so it's really `int i = 241`, so all the `log10`, `% 10`, and `/ 10` are wrong.

Comment: @Sean is it a binary number or just coincidence that you choose 11,110,001?

Comment: @JohnHascall He explicitly wrote "its supposed to be base 2" -- thereby qualifying for a finishing place in top worst questions of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>    
   void convert_int_to_array(unsigned int);   


   int main()
   {
           unsigned int a = 12345678;
           convert_int_to_array(a);
           return 0;
   }       

  void convert_int_to_array(unsigned int a)
  {
          int array[25];    // array large enough for an integer
          int i = 0, count = 0;
          unsigned int num = a;
          memset(array, '\0', 20);  // I've not included the header file for this.
                                     // gives a warning on compilation.

          while(num > 0)
          {
                  array[i] = num % 10;
                  num = num / 10;
                  ++i;
                  ++count;
          }       

          for(i = count; i>=0;--i)
          {
                  printf("array[%d] = %d\n",i, array[i]);
                  // or
                  printf("%d", array[i]);
                  // dont use both the printf statements, else you will see a   
                  // messed up output.
          }       
  }
```

BINARY REPRESENTATION :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  struct bit
  {
           int a : 1;
  };

  int  main()
  {
          struct bit b;
          int d ,f,i;
          d=f=256;   // take any number of your choice
          printf("binary representation of 256:\n");
          for(i = 15; i>=0 ; i--)  //assuming that the number wont have more than 
                                   // 15 DIGITS
          {       
                  f=f>>i;
                  b.a = f;
                  //d= d>>1;
                  f=d;
                  printf("%d",b.a);
          }       
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The OP says "its supposed to be base 2". That is, he doesn't really mean `int i = 11110001`, he means `int i = 0xF1`.

Comment: @JimBalter - Regardless of the representation of the integer, I   
think this code works fine as far as integers are concerned.
For a few test case I took integers in hexadecimal form and  
it worked.
But please do tell me if it fails or can fail in any case ?

Comment: Eh? The OP wants a binary representation, but you're generating a decimal representation  -- along with all the other answers ... because the OP so very badly framed his question.